# Filtering on many to many field in the child model from parent model is too slow in Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have a query where I get a list of org_id, city, pincode and I want parents name field(which can be multiple).
I have tried with the below queries and I am able to achieve it. But the performance of the query is too slow.
Can anyone improve my queries for better speed or if you have any other approach to tackle the problem is much appreciated.

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)


class RelatedModel(models.Model):
    org_name = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)
    pincode = models.CharField(max_length=125, blank=True, null=True, db_index=True)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('org_name', 'city', 'pincode')

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.OneToOneField(Parent, on_delete = models.CASCADE, related_name='child_parent')
    tags = models.ManyToManyField(RelatedModel, blank=True, related_name='tags_relatedmodel')
```

Input data:

```
    data = [{"org_name":"Samaritan", "city":"Delhi", "pincode":"500800"},{"org_name":"Whitefield", "city":"Bengaluru"}]
```

Query:

```
query_fields = Q()
    for i in data:
        if i.pincode == "" or i.pincode == None:
            query_fields = query_fields | Q(tags__org_name=i.org_name, tags__city=i.city)
        else:
            query_fields = query_fields | Q(tags__org_name=i.org_name, tags__city=i.city, tags__pincode=i.pincode)
    
queryset = Child.objects.prefetch_related('tags').filter(parent=OuterRef('id')
                ).filter(query_fields).order_by('parent_id').distinct('parent_id',).values('parent',)
        
result = Parent.objects.filter(id__in=Subquery(queryset)).order_by('-name')
```

This query is taking almost 1min 10seconds to query 200000 records

Comment: Could you please share the DDL for the tables involved and the results from EXPLAIN(analyze, verbose, buffers, settings) for the queries involved? By the way, a loop is most of the time slow by design. How many queries do you execute for these 200000 records?

Comment: SQL Generated for above query:

```
SELECT "parent"."name" FROM "parent"  
WHERE ("parent"."id" IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT ON (U0."parent_id") U0."parent_id" FROM "child" U0 
   INNER JOIN "child_tags" U2 ON (U0."id" = U2."child_id") 
   INNER JOIN "tags" U3 ON (U2."tags_id" = U3."id") 
   WHERE (
    U0."parent_id" = ("parent"."id") 
    AND (
     (U3."org_name" = 'Samaritan' AND U3."city" = 'Delhi' AND U3."pincode" = "500800") 
     OR (U3."org_name" = 'Whitefield' AND U3."city" = 'Bengaluru'))) 
   ORDER BY U0."parent_id" ASC)) 
    ORDER BY "parent"."name" DESC
```

Comment: @FrankHeikens We execute almost 50 to 100 queries per minute during business hours.

Comment: `Yes, this might work. But i want to add a new order filter on this query based on other fields in the model. Then this is not possible. ` Can you add more details?